# Add class to ruby module in runtime

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I need to add class into the class (or module) in runtime. For example: I have **Module M, Class A.**
I need to add a new **Class B** to **Module M**.
I've tried to do:

```
M.module_eval do
  class B
  end
end
```

But it doesnt work.

I know that (for example) if I want to **add a method** to existing ***class A***, I would do

```
class << A
def method
end
end
```

But how to add a Class to a Module or Class?

Comment: What's wrong with `module M ; class B ; end ; end`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is concerned specifically with adding a class at runtime. The class is to be created within an existing module, but, as will be seen, that is almost incidental and is of questionable utility.

**Adding a class to a module at runtime**

To assist in the construction of classes within a given module at runtime we might construct a method `class_factory`.

```
def class_factory(mod, class_name, consts, meths, instance_meths,
   accessors)
  class_obj = mod.const_set(class_name, Class.new)
  consts.each { |const,val| class_obj.const_set(const,val) }
  meths.each do |name,body| 
    class_obj.singleton_class.
    instance_eval("define_method(:#{name}) #{body}")
  end
  instance_meths.each do |name,body| 
    class_obj.instance_eval("define_method(:#{name}) #{body}")
  end
  accessors.each do |accessor,inst_var| 
    class_obj.public_send(accessor, inst_var)
  end
  class_obj
end
```

Let's try it.

```
module M
end
```

```
class_obj = class_factory(
  M,
  "B",
  { 'A'=>7, 'D'=>'cat' },
  { greeting: '{ |n| "Cat\'s have #{n} lives" }' },
  { initialize: '{ |name| @name = name }',
    say_name: '{ "My name is #{@name}" }' },
  { attr_accessor: "name" }
)
  #=> M::B
```

```
class_obj == M::B
  #=> true 
M::B.constants
  #=> [:A, :D] 
class_obj.methods(false)
  #=> [:greeting] 
M::B.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:say_name, :name=, :name] 
class_obj.greeting(9)
  #=> "Cat's have 9 lives" 
M::B.greeting(5) 
  #=> "Cat's have 5 lives"
```

```
instance = M::B.new "Lola" # or class_obj.new "Lola"
  #=> #<M::B:0x000056cb6e766840 @name="Lola"> 
instance.say_name
  #=> "My name is Lola" 
instance.name    
  #=> "Lola" 
instance.name = "Lo"    
  #=> "Lo" 
instance.name    
  #=> "Lo"
```

It could be that your code may contain static expressions such as these, and the only dynamic part is the construction of the class.

On the other hand, the class may be used dynamically as well. For example:

```
mod = "M"
cl  = "B"
name = "Lola"
meth = "say_name"
```

Then:

```
Object.const_get("#{mod}::#{cl}").new(name).public_send(meth)
  #=> "My name is Lola"
```

or

```
class_obj.new(name).public_send(meth)
  #=> "My name is Lola"
```

**How best to reference dynamically-created classes**

We have just seen various ways to reference a dynamically-created class. Depending on requirements,  `M::B` versus `class_obj` and  `Object.const_get("#{mod}::#{cl}")` versus `class_obj`. Clearly, the use of `class_obj` is simplest in both cases and has the additional advantage that references to `class_obj` need not be changed if, in future, `M` or `B` in `M::B` are changed.

**Are the advantages to creating classes dynamically that are members of a module?**

Recall that the main reason to create a class within a module is create a namespace, so that, for example, `M1::C` and `M2::C` do not create a name conflict. However, if we reference a dynamically-created class by its (unique) object (rather than its name, a constant) that is held by a variable (here `class_obj`) there is no need for the namespace. So the answer to the question I posed in this section is "no".

Moreover, if we reference a dynamically-created class by its object, there is no reason to assign a name to the class. We therefore could modify `class_factory` as follows:

```
def class_factory(consts, meths, instance_meths, accessors)
  Class.new do
    consts.each { |const,val| const_set(const,val) }
    meths.each do |name,body| 
          singleton_class.
          instance_eval("define_method(:#{name}) #{body}")
    end
    instance_meths.each do |name,body| 
      instance_eval("define_method(:#{name}) #{body}")
    end
    accessors.each do |accessor,inst_var| 
      public_send(accessor, inst_var)
    end
  end
end
```

```
class_obj = class_factory(
  { 'A'=>7, 'D'=>'cat' },
  { greeting: '{ |n| "Cat\'s have #{n} lives" }' },
  { initialize: '{ |name| @name = name }',
     say_name: '{ "My name is #{@name}" }' },
  { attr_accessor: "name" }
)
  #=> #<Class:0x000056cb6eaeefd0>
```

The object held by `class_obj` is called an *anonymous class* because it has no name (that is a constant).

```
class_obj.constants
  #=> [:A, :D] 
class_obj.methods(false)
  #=> [:greeting] 
class_obj.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:say_name, :name=, :name]
```

```
instance = class_obj.new "Billy-Bob"
  #=> #<#<Class:0x000056cb6eaeefd0>:
  #             0x000056cb6eb183d0 @name="Billy-Bob"> 
instance.say_name
  #=> "My name is Billy-Bob" 
instance.name
  #=> "Billy-Bob" 
instance.name = "BB"
  #=> "BB"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder whats the difference between your answer and ModuleName.const_set(:ClassName, Class.new) ?

Comment: If you have a name in a variable (i.e. you don't know the name at the time of writing your code), you cannot use the first syntax, but the second one works.

Comment: `Class.new` yields the class object, so you can move the dynamic constant assignment into the block, e.g. `Class.new { |klass| M.const_set(:B, klass) }`

Comment: How to add fields to the created class? e.x 
`add self.searchable_supported = true
      self.change_no_details = true
      self.bulk_edit_supported = false
      field_attributes :issue_label`

Comment: @A.Askarov you can define an attribute in the class' singleton class.